# Call default method from other interface in another default method

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, java-8, default-method

This code crashes:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      Person person = new Person();
      person.selectMe();
    }
}

class Entity {}

interface EntityNameable<T extends Entity> {
  default String getSomething() {
    return "";
  } 
}

interface EntityNameableSelectable<T extends EntityNameable> {
  default String selectMe() { 
    return ((EntityNameable) this).getSomething();
  } 
}

class Person extends Entity implements EntityNameableSelectable {

}
```

This code can be executed by copy pasting it into https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Person cannot be cast to EntityNameable
    at EntityNameableSelectable.selectMe(MyClass.java:18)
    at MyClass.main(MyClass.java:4)
```

It crashes because `person` can not be casted to `EntityNameable`. Why not? A `person` is always an `Entity`, `EntityNamable` and `EntityNameableSelectable` right?

I am also wondering why I need to cast this to `EntityNameable` to call method `getSomething`, as every implementing class should have that method. Why is the cast needed? It has to do something with the crash...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am also wondering why I need to cast this to EntityNameable to call method getSomething, as every implementing class should have that method.

`EntityNameableSelectable` is not an `EntityNameable`. `EntityNameableSelectable` does not extend that interface, so no methods are inherited.

Probably, you wanted `EntityNameableSelectable` to extend `EntityNameable`, so you would be able to call `getSomething()`.

```
interface EntityNameableSelectable<T extends Entity> extends EntityNameable<T> {
    default String selectMe() {
        return getSomething();
    }
}
```

> A `Person` is always an `Entity`, `EntityNamable` and `EntityNameableSelectable`, right?

Only if `EntityNameableSelectable` extends `EntityNameable` or `Person` implements `EntityNameable`.

If you defined `EntityNameableSelectable` as I mentioned above, the `Person` class would look like:

```
class Person extends Entity implements EntityNameableSelectable<Person> {}
```

Answer (score 2):

> A `Person` is always an `Entity`, `EntityNamable` and `EntityNameableSelectable` right?

A `Person` extends `Entity` and implements `EntityNameableSelectable`, but it doesn't implement `EntityNameable`, no.

I don't know exactly what you're trying to do, but I suspect `<T extends EntityNameable>` is not doing what you want it to do. Try having `EntityNameableSelectable` extend `EntityNameable` instead:

```
interface EntityNameableSelectable extends EntityNameable {
  default String selectMe() { 
    return getSomething();
  } 
}
```

Similarly, making `EntityNameable` have a generic `T` parameter may not be correct either. In your sample code `T` isn't doing anything, so you might just remove it.

```
interface EntityNameable {
  default String getSomething() {
    return "";
  } 
}
```